# Specific Exceptions vs Exception

Tags: java, exception

This may be a very dumb question, but I'm trying to understand why it is significant. Why is it important to use a specific exception instead of just using Exception. Here is an example:

```
List<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    testList.add(1, "String");
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above example has the specific exception this would raise. Why is it important to have `IndexOutOFBoundsException` instead of just using `Exception`. I know using `Exception` with `printStackTrace()` will show you what exception is really being raised.

Comment: Never, ever, has catching `IndexOutOfBoundsException` made any sense. You should handle it _before_ it happens. And the fact that it is named `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is to tell you more information as to what went wrong.

Comment: what if method can raise several different exceptions, how you will distinguish between them?

Comment: You should catch specific exceptions. That is why you have subclasses of exceptions.

Comment: It's almost always the case that you don't want to catch *all* exceptions, but only the ones you can handle at this point in the code.  You *want* to let the rest go through and get handled elsewhere.

Comment: @SureshKoya - Thanks. I'm just learning about exception handling, and learning to use try catch blocks. Is it wise to wrap all your code in try catch blocks, or are they mostly just used for when you try things you aren't sure about, or testing and things of that nature?

Comment: [A specific exception question that was answered in another SO forum.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/184772/throwing-runtime-exception-in-java-application)

Comment: @Colby, if you're just getting started learning about exception handling, my beginner's tip is just this: _don't catch exceptions_. You will only make your life harder when debugging later. If there is an exception, then there is a way to avoid that exception without catching it 99% of the time.

Comment: @DavidS Thanks for the explanation and answer. I'll be sure to check out the book you mentioned. I've noticed that I can find easy ways around the errors I have been running into with the sandbox code that we have to write for my class. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question, but it's also very a big question. In his famous book, *Effective Java*, Joshua Bloch dedicates an entire chapter to Exception best practices. One of his recommendations that's relevant here is this:

> Use checked exceptions for recoverable conditions and runtime exceptions for programming errors.

The reason this is relevant to the code you posted is that by catching Exception you're ignoring the difference between "recoverable conditions" and "programming errors". You're saying, "I don't care what's wrong, I'm going to handle it."

While there is a time and place for this sort of handling, it's usually at the very highest level of your application. For example, many web application frameworks display a nice-looking error page to the user in the case of an unhandled exception. They do this using some mechanism similar to `catch Exception` to provide a nicer user experience and prevent the entire web application framework from crashing.

On the other hand, if some careless developer were to `catch Exception` somewhere in low level code, and then caught an exception he didn't mean to, there is a good chance the application would break in other ways, worsening the user experience and making debugging far more difficult.

### See also

- *Effective Java*, Second Edition, by Joshua Bloch

  - Item 58: Use checked exceptions for recoverable conditions and runtime exceptions for programming errors
  - Item 61: Throw exceptions appropriate to the abstraction [which also implies to *catch* exceptions appropriate to the abstraction]
  - Item 65: Don't ignore exceptions [catching Exception is like ignoring a whole class of possible errors]